# Add threads in Julia after initializing

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, julia

I know that I can use multiple threads on Julia by initializing a REPL with

```
julia --threads 4
```

but is there a way to add threads from within Julia? I can change nthreads by doing this

```
julia> Threads.nthreads()
1

julia> Threads.nthreads() = 4

julia> Threads.nthreads()
4
```

but I don't notice any performance increase. I have a feeling that setting the number of threads this way does not work the way I am expecting it to.

Comment: "setting the number of threads this way does not work" - yep, you're basically redefining the `Threads.nthreads` function here

Answer (score 2):

You cannot increase the thread pool once Julia is started.

Perhaps the best option is to use `auto` with the thread number parameter:

```
$ julia --threads auto


julia> Threads.nthreads()
8
```

Another important thing to know is that Julia can call C libraries that have their own independent thread pools. Linear algebra BLAS is the most notable example:

```
$ julia --threads 2

julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> BLAS.get_num_threads()
8

julia> Threads.nthreads()
2
```

Comment: Just to add.. that you can add _processes_ at run time with `addprocs(n)`, but not threads